# Counterpart of ExecuteScalar in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My stored procedure has SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() after the insert is done. Using  ADO.net provides
ExecuteScalar to retrieve the same while calling the stored proc.

Is a similar feature available in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore(Version=3.1.5.0) which could return  SCOPE_IDENTITY after sp is executed. I see it has ExecuteSqlRaw but it just returns the rows affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
using (var db = new NorthwindContext())
{
    var result = db.Set<IntReturn>()
    .FromSqlRaw("exec dbo.Scalar")
    .AsEnumerable()
    .First().Value;
    
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

See my blog post here for more details: https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/05/26/ef-core-fromsql-scalar.html

Comment: Not debating - but is that really how one gets a scalar value?  That's absolutely awful!

Comment: Yes, you could just use DbReader .Execute scalar...